# iPhone Device Management function gone

Tags: iphone, settings, enterprise-distribution, device-management

✓ I have searched the internet and no solution/useful information found.

- iOS version: 11.4.1
- only one feedback until now
- first time installation

The expected result looks like:

[image: normal]

the *Device Management* option presented under *VPN*

but doesn`t know why it just gone.

any suggestions?

Comment: restart iPhone 'fix' the issue in my case